# Open telegram bot chat without start command

Tags: bots, telegram

How can a telegram bot open self bot chat without start command, in answerCallbackQuery method, responding to inline buttons?

This opens bot's chat, but appends "/start" into chat

```
https://t.me/<bot-name>?start=<start-parameter>
```

This one opens bot's chat without appending "/start". But seems to me more of a bug than a correct way.

```
https://t.me/<bot-name>?start=a:b
```

This other ones report URL_INVALID:

```
https://t.me/<bot-name>?start=
https://t.me/<bot-name>?start
https://t.me/<bot-name>?
https://t.me/<bot-name>
https://t.me/<bot-name>/
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to redirect to the bot's chat with a command rather than `/start`. The only 2 parameters that are accepted in the bot URL are:

- `start` which is for starting the bot in private chat, and
- `startgroup` which lets the user choose a group to start the bot in.

And there's something to be aware of: Their values will be appended after a space after the `/start`. For example if your URL is t.me/yourbot?start=a, your bot will get a message with the text `/start a`.

Comment: Yeah. I'm aware of that. The problem is that I just want the "/start" command the first time the user clics on inlineButton. Next times my only intention is to open bot's chat window. No command is needed because all "start" actions were taken.

Comment: Well, you cannot redirect the user from a response to a callback query, but you can have a URL button instead.